# How can I have an opaque UIView as a subview of a semi-transparent UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a UIView with an alpha of 0.5 which I add as a subview to my primary view in order to gray-out everything else.  I want to add an additional UIView to this gray UIView as a subview - the problem is that when I do this, my newly-added subview is also partially transparent.

Is there any way to make a subview "ignore" the alpha value of its superview and be itself fully opaque?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, not really. What you want is to take your overlay view, and make it just have a clear background color. As a subview of that new overlay place your view that will grey things out. And as a sibling view to that put your view you want to be opaque.

```
[OpaqueView] [DimmingView]
     |             |
      [OverlayView]
```

Comment: Even simpler: I just use this as the background color: `UIColor *bg = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];`, so I don't have to add an additional overlay view.

Comment: The answer below seems to be more correct than this. Just set the background color with alpha instead of setting the alpha value of the UIView

Answer (score 113):

Set the UIView background color alpha not it's alpha directly.

**Objective-C**

```
UIView *view;
...
view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.6];
```

It's not the same as:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];    
view.alpha = .6;
```

**Swift**

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
```

Comment: This worked, but can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Don't put it inside the semi-transparent view. Make it a sibling to semi-transparent view and put it over it using z-ordering.

Comment: If you're dealing with anything other than colored backgrounds, this seems to be the real answer here...

Answer (score 2):

**This will only work if you have any image on the background.**

Instead of reducing the `alpha` of `UIView`, add an `UIImageView` on that view and then reduce the alpha of the `UIImageView`.

now add your subviews on the `UIView`.

your subviews will not take the alpha property anymore.. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, any view will inherit the opacity of its parent.

Comment: I normally have a dimmer view specifically for dimming out elements (for instance when using a textField) but this is below anything I want to show as enabled, but above anything I want disabled.